# LEGO Express 60197 displays low battery

Tags: trains, repair, battery

Using new batteries to power the controller - however on connecting the app using Bluetooth the status immediately shows low battery.

Uninstalled the app and reinstalled it with new set of batteries, but no change.

Comment: Are you using rechargeable batteries? Rechargeable batteries have a lower nominal voltage (6 batteries is only 7.2V rather than 9V) and hence the hub will report the batteries being low much faster. The powered up team indicated that rechargeables should work, but perhaps thats false.